# Android P background restriction for Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

In Android P, FCM message will NOT be received if device in deep sleep mode (without cable plugin and screen if off for some time).

I found Google has stated such information for P background restriction [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/09/notifying-your-users-with-fcm.html)

> ★ Note: Starting January 2019, App Restrictions (in Battery Setting) will include restrictions on FCM messages. You can find out if your app is in the restricted state with the isBackgroundRestricted API. Once your app is in the restricted state, no FCM messages will be delivered to the app at all. This will apply to both high and normal priority FCM messages and when app is in either foreground or background.

That means we need to remove this background restriction manually by user! But I still don't figure out how can user do that! when I run isBackgroundRestricted API in my app, it return false.

How should we enable FCM to receive message in backgoround for P release?

Comment: "*That means we need to remove this background restriction manually by user*" -- This is exactly it. I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for. The device owner was given more power to choose which services run on their smartphone. The best approach that you could do is show a prompt (when `isBackgroundRestricted` is true)  and ask the user to allow your app to run background services. Think of it just like runtime permissions.

Comment: @AL Thanks, I run isBackgorundRestricted on my app, but it return false. and I am running my app in a foreground service. if app is running as foreground service, should it be treated as a background and apply background limitation? where to find the settings to remove the background restriction?

Comment: If the `isBackgroundRestricted` value is false, then your app is not restricted. I'm a little bit confused. Foreground is different from background service. The location of the settings may vary per device, but a common example is stated [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#restricted): `such as via: Setting -> Apps and Notification -> [appname] -> Battery`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should disable "Battery Optimization" feature for this specific app which using FCM functionality. about how to disable "Battery Optimization", you can following [this](http://nine-faq.9folders.com/articles/8697-how-to-turn-off-battery-optimization-on-the-google-android-6-7-and-8-devices) steps:

App info->Battery->Battery optimization, then select "All apps" from menu and find your app, select "Don't optimization".